# How to query multiple databases by using common mysql query?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to query two databases as a common query
example Query :

```
SELECT t1.name,t2.name FROM database1.table1 as t1
INNER JOIN database2.table2 as t2                   
;
```

Comment: Yes, but why twice?

Comment: And what has python got to do with this or node

Comment: yes i removed duplicate query.

Comment: Did you try and fail? Is this just idle curiosity?

Comment: Please edit and fix your post. I can't find a question. What is the problem with the given query?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Actually, I need to query data from two different databases as i mentioned above query not single database with two different tables.

Comment: I can't see a problem with the published code, what issue do you have?

Comment: I know, i read the question. So the answer is YES, and thats the way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT table2.name
FROM database2.table2 as table2
WHERE t1.x1 = table2.x2 
)t2   -- t2 is the alias for this query
```

x1 and x2 are common denominators found in both tables.